# Why Dont get NgClass the Css?

Tags: css, angular

I have a problem, I am using Angular2 , I want have differents styles with ngClass switch the index 'NgFor' but I dont get anything ....

Sorry for my English.

```
<div class='line'></div>
<clr-icon *ngFor="let step of steps; let i = index" shape="circle" 
class='circle' attr.ng-class="circle{{ i + 1 }}"
size="36">
</clr-icon>
<clr-icon *ngIf="steps.length == 1" attr.ng-class="circle{{ 2 }}" shape="circle" class='circle' size="36"></clr-icon>
```

```
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.mycontainer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.step {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;

  .circle {
    color: black;
    margin-top: -30px;
    background-color: white;
  }

  .circle1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0%;
  }
  .circle2 {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0%;
    background-color: black;
    color: yellow;
    /*@calcularposicion();*/
  }
}

.line {
  height: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

In my second circle I would see color 'yellow' but I don't see anything.
If I inspect the Html I have class='circle' and class='circle2'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `attr.ng-class` to `[ngClass]`. NgClass is not an attribute. It is a directive provided by Angular.

```
<clr-icon *ngFor="let step of steps; let i = index" [ngClass]="'circle' + (i + 1)"></clr-icon>


<clr-icon *ngIf="steps.length == 1" [ngClass]="'circle2'"></clr-icon>
```

Comment: well said `NgClass is not an attribute. It is a directive provided by Angular`

Comment: [Angular]
Can't bind to 'ng-class' since it isn't a known property of 'clr-icon'.
1. If 'clr-icon' is an Angular component and it has 'ng-class' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'clr-icon' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

Comment: It is `[ngClass]`, and not `[ng-class]`.

Comment: Glad I could help :)